# Depth func LESS EQUAL not working as expected

Tags: 3d, directx11, graphics-programming, depth-buffer

How is it possible that a fragment is generated, passes the depth test but isn't written to the current render target?

This is the pixel history I see if I capture a frame in RenderDoc:

[image]

The fragment should pass the depth test (same depth of the corresponding pixel in the depthbuffer and depthfunc = Less equal), blending is not enabled, stencil test is not enabled, but the new color is not written.

What am I missing? Is there some other state I'm not taking into account?

Comment: Is it possible the depth values have been rounded for display, and they actually differ in the 4th or 5th decimal place?

Comment: @DMGregory maybe, however RenderDoc highlights depht test failure in the pixel history tab (on the right in the picture) with a red (not green) tint for the corresponding entry and labels it with "Depth test failed"....

Comment: Right, which is what we would expect if the depth value of the new fragment is strictly greater than the stored depth value, even if they round to the same 3-decimal representation for display.